# Word doesnt start with number or asterix and number (regex)

Tags: regex, r

I am using R, version 3.3.1. I have following column:

```
my_column <- 
c("1. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/21. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/2 ", "CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42 ", 
"2. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/22. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/2 ", "CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUĹ , GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUĹ , GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42 ", 
"*1. VlasniÄŤki dio: 1/1*1. VlasniÄŤki dio: 1/1 ", "*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3 ", 
"2. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/22. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/2 ", "ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4 ", 
"3. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/23. SuvlasniÄŤki dio: 1/2 ", "ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156 "
)
```

Strings in column starts with letter, number, *number or *letter. I would like to remove all strings that start with number and *number. I tried following code:

```
my_column[grepl(pattern = "(?=^[^\\*]\\D{2})(?=^\\D)", x = my_column, perl = TRUE)]
# [1] "CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42 "                                    
# [2] "CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUĹ , GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUĹ , GAREĹ NICA KBR. 42 "          
# [3] "ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4 "
# [4] "ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREĹ NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156 "
```

But it returns only strings that start with letter and not * letter words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the start (`^`) of the string, we match zero or more `*`(`\\**`) followed by a number (`[0-9]`)`and negate`!` to extract the elements.

```
my_column[!grepl("^(\\**[0-9])", my_column)]
#[1] "CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "                                    
#[2] "CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "          
#[3] "*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3 "        
#[4] "ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4 "
#[5] "ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156 "
```

Or use `grep` with `invert=TRUE`,

```
grep("^(\\**[0-9])", my_column, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE)
#[1] "CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "                                    
#[2] "CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "          
#[3] "*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3 "        
#[4] "ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4 "
#[5] "ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156 "
```

NOTE: Based on the OP's post `But it returns only strings that start with letter and not * letter words?`

Comment: Thanks. You solution works. Why did you use * for two times?

Comment: @Mislav  As `*` is a metacharacter, we need to escape `\\*` and the second `*` is metacharacter which suggests 0 or more `*`

Answer (score 4):

Try using this:

```
x[!grepl("^\\*?\\d.*$", x)]

[1] "CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC ANDRIJA, GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "                                    
[2] "CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42CRKVENAC LJUBICA ROÄ. VERTUL , GAREL NICA KBR. 42 "          
[3] "*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3*MUHVIÄ† IVAN, ANTUNOV, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA 3 "        
[4] "ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4ANÄAL-MLINARIÄ† BRIGITA, BJELOVAR, V. LISINSKOG KBR. 4 "
[5] "ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156ANÄAL LIDIJA, GAREL NICA, MATIJE GUPCA KBR. 156 "
```

The regex being used here is:

```
^\\*?\\d.*$
```

This will match any entry in your input vector which either begins with asterisk *or* begins with an asterisk followed by a number (but not followed by anything else).  This resulting logical vector is then *negated*, because you don't want to match these strings.  You can explore this regex here:

## Regex101

Comment: op's solution already does this `identical(x[!grepl("^(\\d|\\*).*$", x)], x[grepl("(?=^[^\\*]\\D{2})(?=^\\D)", x, perl = TRUE)]) ## [1] TRUE`

Comment: @rawr I went by the title of the question, which isn't what they really wanted.

Comment: using `(\\d|\\*\\d)` is the same as `\\*?\\d` and the second is quicker in case you find it useful